# Create List<String> with JPype

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, jpype

I'm trying to use the stanford parser in my python code by accessing its methods through JPype.
Here's my relevant (python3.4) code:

```
    tokens = ['The', 'monkey', 'was', 'shot', 'and', 'killed', '.']
    jTokens = jpype.java.util.ArrayList()
    for t in tokens:
        jTokens.add(t)#jpype.java.lang.String(t))
    print("DEBUGGING jTokens:", jTokens, type(jTokens))
    self.parser.parseStrings(jTokens)
```

The function parseStrings in the java code (from the stanford parser) looks like this:

```
  public Tree parseStrings(List<String> lst) {
    List<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
    for (String word : lst) {
      words.add(new Word(word));
    }
    return parse(words);
  }
```

The error message I'm getting:

```
Loading parser from serialized file /home/igor/Downloads/stanford-parser-full-2015-01-30/edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser ... done [0.8 sec].
DEBUGGING jTokens: [The, monkey, was, shot, and, killed, .] <class 'jpype._jclass.java.util.ArrayList'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./stanfordSnake.py", line 113, in <module>
    sp.parse("The monkey was shot and killed.")
  File "./stanfordSnake.py", line 92, in parse
    self.parser.parseStrings(jTokens)
RuntimeError: No matching overloads found. at src/native/common/jp_method.cpp:121
```

I have only very limited knowledge of Java. I'm guessing that this error message is trying to tell me that the type of argument that I'm passing on to it is incorrect. If that is indeed what is wrong, then apparantly "jpype._jclass.java.util.ArrayList" is not matching List(String) (meant lessThan, greaterThan here, but didn't come out very well in the post). If have tried adding the strings in the (python) list explicitly as (java) strings like this: jpype.java.lang.String(t) (see comment). But I'm getting the same error message with that.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I guess you're using the the Python 3 version of JPype from tcalmant repo. It has some bugs especially regarding matching overloads problems, that have been fixed in the official JPype1 (originell's repo). Your sample works for me using JPype1. If you have the Java code try to make sure there is only one method named parseStrings and there are no getter/setters or attributes named parseStrings to work around the bugs.

Comment: Hmm, interesting... I'm now using JPype1_py3-0.5.5.2 (was indeed using the one from tcalmant) but now I get some "function not Callable" errors on the same code that was executed without problems before. E.g. for self.parser.parseStrings(jTokens), it now reports:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./stanfordSnake.py", line 114, in <module>
        sp.parse("The monkey was shot and killed.")
      File "./stanfordSnake.py", line 93, in parse
        self.parser.parseStrings(jTokens)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/JPype1_py3-0.5.5.2-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/jpype/_jpackage.py", line 53, in __call__
        raise TypeError("Package {0} is not Callable".format(self.__name))
    TypeError: Package edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.parseStrings is not Callable

Comment: So I now have a new puzzle :) Thanks a lot for responding though!

Comment: JPype1_py3? Where do you have that from? JPype1 Python 2 only at the moment. See https://github.com/originell/jpype/issues/119

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JPype1-py3/0.5.5.2 Thanks for the link, as I hadn't yet found out that the one from originell could be made to work with python3 with some fiddling and meddling. Checking that out now.

Comment: @bastian; I'm afraid I need a little bit more help. I read the discussion and looked at the (french) walkthrough in your link. I ended up installing/trying this version: https://github.com/tcalmant/jpype-py3

Comment: It seemed to me that this jpype-py3 version included exactly the steps that are described in the walk through already. But after installing and trying my code, I keep getting the same error (no matching overloads found). What did you do that makes it work for you?

Comment: I got it running using the Python 2 version of JPype which doesn't suffer from some bugs. There has been put some effort on porting the working version to Python 3 (see the link I've already posted) but it's not finished yet. You either have to move your code to python 2 or try to find a way around your problems using my advices: "make sure there is only one method named parseStrings and there are no getter/setters or attributes named parseStrings"

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for your response (again). I don't really like to move my code back to python 2 (would mean fixing a lot of dependencies/other packages I'm using too). I'm sure there is only one method by this name, and pretty sure there is nothing else anywhere by the same name. However; I'll just keep trying. In case I get there I'll be sure to post it here as an answer for others. Thanks for your help and pointers!